# No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"reviews", :id=>"2", :user_id=>#<Profile id: 2...} missing required keys: [:profile_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on user_profile_reviews and have got stuck. I have 3 models for now, and I know, that doing a separate model for a profile wasn't really a great idea, but since all my routes depend on this structure, meaning the links in all the views also, I decided not to change it.

To give you a clearer understanding:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :user, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks', registrations: "users/registrations" }
    resources :users do
        resources :profiles do
            resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create]
        end
    end
    root 'home#index'
end
```

Here are my controllers:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      def index
        @profiles = Profile.all
      end

      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
        @reviews = Review.where("profile_id = ?", params[:id])
      end

      def new
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      end

      def edit
        @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
      end

      def create
        @profile = current_user.build_profile(profile_params)
        respond_to do |format|
          if @profile.save
            format.html { redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user.id, current_user.profile.id), notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @profile.update(profile_params)
            format.html { redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user.id, current_user.profile.id), notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @profile.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to profiles_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        def set_profile
          @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
        end

        def profile_params
          params.permit(:about, :rating, :avatar)
        end
    end
```

Reviews

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_profile
  before_filter :set_review, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @review = Review.new

  end

def create
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
    @review = @profile.reviews.build(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id

    if @review.save
        redirect_to @profile
    else
        redirect_to @profile, notice: "Error saving"
    end
end

  private

  def review_params
    params.permit(:content, :rating)
  end

def set_pfofile
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
  end

  def set_review
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

So now, I am trying to create a form for reviews, which I am then rendering in Profiles#show, and getting the mistake above.

```
<div class="submit-review">
  <%= form_for [@review, :url => user_profile_reviews_path(@profile)] do |f| %>
    <label for="review">How was your experience?</label><br>
    <%= f.label :rating %>
    <%= f.select :rating, options_for_select([["Please select one", ""], 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]) %>

    <%= f.input :content, placeholder:"Please enter your feedback here" %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit your review", class: "btn btn-default" %> <br><br>
  <% end %>

Showing ... /_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"reviews", :id=>"2", :user_id=>#<Profile id: 2, about: "lena", rating: 3, created_at: "2019-11-22 21:27:03", updated_at: "2019-11-22 21:27:03", user_id: 2>}, missing required keys: [:profile_id]
```

But, as I see, it gets to the profile, I am onto, so I don't understand what's the issue here.

Comment: you've got `def set_pfofile` at the end (profile typo) then `set_review` actually sets a Profile object at reviews_controller. also, check your routes, if you have users > profiles > reviews then the routes for the review requires a user and a profile parameter, you are passing only `@profile` at `user_profile_reviews_path(@profile)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this worked perfectly for solving the described problem with missing id.

```
form_for([@profile.user, @profile, @review], :url => user_profile_reviews_path(@profile.user, @profile)) do |f|
```

I was getting another error though:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

I saw then, that in my Profile#show I wasn't defining @review. Only reviews. So I did it this way:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    @review = Review.new
    @reviews = Review.where("profile_id = ?", params[:id])
  end
```

I can now finally go to profile and there is a review window, which is great! I can't save the reviews though, as another error is showing up. But that's different case. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Something wrong with the syntax, try this

```
= form_for([@profile.user, @profile, @review], :url => user_profile_reviews_path(@profile.user, @profile)) do |f|
```

Since your resources are nested, you need to pass `user`, `profile` and then `review` as the first argument in `form_for`

**Suggestion**: Looking at your code, you don't even need `user_id`, you can avoid nesting `profile` and `review` under `user` in routes.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanky you so much! Now it has changed to another error: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty ‍♀️